# Overnight in OSL between SFO and LYR -- can I stay on the same side of security?

Tags: airport-security, oslo, osl

I am flying from the US (from San Francisco), through Frankfurt (transferring planes), and landing in Oslo close to midnight local time. The next morning, I fly out of Oslo to Longyearbyen Svalbard. **Will I have to go through security again, or can I just stay overnight on the secure side of the terminal?**

A few other potentially relevant details:

- I will be carry-on only, so baggage claim is not an issue
- The SFO to FRA leg will be on Condor, the FRA to OSL leg will be on Lufthansa (though booked with Condor still), and the OSL to LYR leg will be on SAS (booked through SAS). I am switching both airlines and tickets in OSL.
- In principle, [you can sleep in OSL overnight](https://www.sleepinginairports.net/guides/oslo-gardermoen-airport-guide.htm), though I haven't been able to confirm this still holds post-pandemic
- I have US citizenship

Comment: Can you confirm that the last leg is on the same ticket as the previous one?

Comment: According to Flightaware F-gates are used at OSL for OSL-LYR which are international according to the airport's webpage

Comment: @jcaron, they are different tickets booked separately

Comment: Since Germany and Norway are both in the Schengen Area, won't you already pass through immigration at FRA and arrive at the domestic section of OSL?

Comment: @Bernard Yes, immigration will be in Frankfurt, but (since Norway has a lot of small airports without customs I guess) there is a true domestic area at OSL with a special process for smooth connections from outside Norway with checked-through luggage for some flights. So arrival will be in the Schengen-part of the international area, departure from the non-Schengen part.

Answer (score 3):

**You will not need to go through security again, but you will have to go through passport control**. Since Svalbard is governed under the Svalbard Treaty, flights are from the international terminal, and since you're coming from FRA, you will have already gone through immigration to get into the Schengen area. This is not an issue though, as there are plenty of good places to sleep in the domestic section of OSL. Passport control opens at around 5:30am.

There are a few potential exceptions to the above:

- If you're coming in from outside the Schengen area, you will likely be able to stay in the international terminal
- If you have checked luggage, you will need to fully exit the secure area and go back through security again
- Some flights to Svalbard go through Tromso; for these, you will typically go through passport control on your way out in Tromso, and thus not need to in OSL (ie, you leave from the domestic terminal)